# Making a class-array dynamic in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I've created a Java class called 'Book'. Using this class I'm willing to update information about a new object 'book1'. I'm also wanting to add Author information into the object 'book1'. So, I've dynamically allocated memory using a class-array called 'Author[ ]'. By this I mean there's a separate code in which I've created a class called 'Author' with its own set of instance variables. I'm not getting into that now. However, when I'm testing the class 'Book' using another class called 'TestBook' there's no compilation error BUT I'm getting the following message in the console window when I'm running the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Book.addAuthors(Book.java:34)
    at TestBook.main(TestBook.java:12)
```

The code for 'Book' is shown below:

```
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private Author[] A = new Author[];
    private int numAuthors = 0;
    private double price;
    private int qtyInStock;

    public Book(String n, Author[] authors, double p) {
        name = n;
        A = authors;
        price = p;
    }
    public Book(String n, Author[] authors, double p, int qIS) {
        name = n;
        A = authors;
        price = p;
        qtyInStock = qIS;
    }
    public Book(String n, double p, int qIS) {
        name = n;
        price = p;
        qtyInStock = qIS;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /*
    public Author getAuthors() {
        return A;
    }
    */
    public void addAuthors(Author newAuthor) {
        A[numAuthors] = newAuthor;              // THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR POINTS TO
        ++numAuthors;
    }
    public void printAuthors() {
        /*
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
        */
        for (int i = 0; i < numAuthors; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
    }
    public void setPrice(double p) {
        price = p;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setqtyInStock(int qIS) {
        qtyInStock = qIS;
    }
    public int getqtyInStock() {
        return qtyInStock;
    }
    /*
    public String getAuthorName() {
        return A.getName();
    }
    public String getAuthorEmail() {
        return A.getEmail();
    }
    public char getAuthorGender() {
        return A.getGender();
    }
    */
    public String toString() {  
        /*
        return getName() + " " + getAuthor() + " Book price: " + getPrice() + 
        " Qty left in stock: " + getqtyInStock();
        */
        //return getName() + " is written by " + A.length + " authors.";
        return getName() + " is written by " + numAuthors + " authors.";
    }

}
```

The code for 'TestBook' is shown below:

```
public class TestBook {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Author[] authors = new Author[2];
        //authors[0] = new Author("Tapasvi Dumdam Thapashki",        "tapasvi@thapashki.com", 'M');
        //authors[1] = new Author("Paul Rand", "paulie@aol.com", 'M');
        Book book1 = new Book("The Quickie Man", 69.00, 5);
        //System.out.println(book1.toString());
        //book1.setqtyInStock(5);
        //System.out.println(book1.toString());
        //System.out.println(book1.getAuthorName() + " " + book1.getAuthorEmail());
        //book1.printAuthors();
        book1.addAuthors(new Author("Linda Lee", "lindalee@grinchtown.com", 'F'));
        book1.addAuthors(new Author("Joseph Caputo", "caputo@lfp.com", 'M'));
        System.out.println(book1.toString());
        book1.printAuthors();
    }

}
```

The code for 'Author' is shown below:

```
public class Author {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private char gender;

    public Author(String n, String e, char g) {
        name = n;
        email = e;
        gender = g;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setEmail(String e) {
        email = e;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public String toString() {  
        return getName() + " [" + getGender() + "] " + getEmail();
    }
}
```

I'd like some help with this.

Comment: `private Author[] A = new Author[];` what does it mean ????

Comment: I suggest you replace `Author[] A` with `List<Author> authors` and you won't need to resize or keep track of the number of Authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify the size of the Array.

```
private Author[] A = new Author[15];
```

For making a dynamic array you can use ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<Author> list = new ArrayList<Author>();
```

addAuthors()

```
public void addAuthors(Author newAuthor) {

        list.add(newAuthor);
}
```

printAuthors()

```
public void printAuthors() {

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! I made changes to the 'Book' class according to your suggestion. However, I'm still getting errors saying - cannot find symbol, symbol: class ArrayList. I've changed the 2nd argument in the first two constructors (by the name 'Book') from 'Author[ ] authors' to 'ArrayList<Author> authors' and have also made other necessary changes while assigning 'authors' within the constructors i.e from 'A = authors' to 'list = authors'. I hope you get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I think, you forgot to import ArrayList class, `import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: Thanks for taking time and helping me out. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `Author` array with proper size like `private Author[] A = new Author[4];`